# OTB plugin was not found

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

How can I do segmentation using OTB plugin? I searched it in the Plugin section but was not able to find it out.

Comment: What is your problem exactly? "How to do segmentation using OTB?" or "How to install OTB plugin?"

Answer (score 4):

Visit [The QGIS-OTB plugin](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/QGISInterface.html) page. It contains instructions.

> #### The QGIS-OTB plugin (requires QGIS > 3.2)
>
> With QGIS < 3.8 you will need to manually install the plugin. You can follow the instruction here: https://gitlab.orfeo-toolbox.org/orfeotoolbox/qgis-otb-plugin#otb-provider-for-qgis-processing
>
> With QGIS > 3.8, the plugin is already in the QGIS core. So you just need to install OTB and activate the plugin: https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/QGISInterface.html#open-processing-settings
>
> #### Download and Install OTB
>
> OTB is not distributed with qgis-otb-plugin. It is a separate project and has its own git repository. Download > latest OTB version: https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/download/.
>
> #### Configure plugin in QGIS
>
> Restart QGIS, then install the OTB plugin: `> Plugins -> Manage and Install Plugins`.
>
> Click on Installed tab on left and make sure box next to OrfeoToolBox (OTB) is checked.
>
> #### Open processing settings
>
> `Settings -> Options -> Processing` (left panel)
>
> You can see OTB under “Providers”:
>
> - Expand OTB tab
> - Tick Activate option
> - Set OTB folder. This is location of your OTB installation.
> - Set OTB application folder. This is location of your OTB applications. `<OTB_FOLDER>/lib/otb/applications`
> - Click “ok” to save settings and close dialog. If settings are correct, you will have OTB algorithms loaded in Processing toolbox